# Home page of Wordpress website not showing up

Tags: wordpress, html, webserver, hostmonster

Really a newbie question here, since I just started working with Wordpress.

How do I get to the home page of my Wordpress website!? I am hosting a Wordpress website on my personal shared server, and when I go to www.nishantkelkar.org/wp-admin/about.php, it shows the typical admin panel that I'm used to seeing on Wordpress. Then I went about and created some test content (a Hello world post), and said "Publish". It says "Your post has been published" and gives me a link. When I click that link, I get redirected to the index page with an index of all my files in that folder! - http://www.nishantkelkar.org/?p=10&preview=true.

Am I doing something wrong? I just want to be able to see my freshly created content!

Comment: Have some reading on basic WordPress stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you need to set your DirectoryIndex to index.php but it is difficult to say from just the information you provided.

Comment: Hi, what other information would you need? Would be glad to provide it.

Comment: When you have created this about? Have you created page or post?